# Coded UI test with test agent on VM

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs, virtual-machine, coded-ui-tests, mtm

I configured the test agent on VM, but when initiate a test from MTM/TFS build, the test agent is not performing the GUI test. i can see a successful call from the test controller to the VM test agent. The VM is not lock and in active window screen but somehow its not performing the GUI action that i coded. 
it threw below exception after test failed:

"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: 
The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA'ControlType:"

This is very common exception where cannot find the control, but the control is on the screen. 
i did the same config by installing test agent on my pyciscal workstation, the test agent able perform the test successfully from the test controller. this is confirm i do not have any problem on my testscript,testcontroller and tfs build. Is there any missing config or permission on my VM? or VM do not have mouse/keyboard causing the GUI test failure?

Comment: Does your test setting include a controller name and is Environment set to Remote?

Comment: yes, the controller is ready. there is no issue when i configure my test agent on local/physical PC. only if i setup test agent on VM, when i run the test, i can see the 'Test agent status' = running, 'Current running Test'= TestCaseiRan.. but at the end the testcase will fail because not able to perform mouse click or search for control type.